# get a src atrribute using xpath

Tags: python, xpath

I am using python with 'requests' and 'lxml' modules to create a parsed HTML object.
My assignment is to find all of the links that contain the string "googleadservices" in the following page:

http://www.euronews.com/2015/03/20/uber-taxis-overtake-new-york-yellow-cabs/

My xpath query is

```
//script[contains(@src,'google')]/@src
```

I think that it should return me the value of the src attribute of every script node, yet it fails as I see the following query results:

```
/js/google.js
https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js
```

Note that:

```
http://partner.googleadservices.com/gpt/pubads_impl_58.js
```

Is missing!!!

I guess that I'm missing a delicate syntax point and I'll be glad to be enlightened.

Comment: `curl http://www.euronews.com/2015/03/20/uber-taxis-overtake-new-york-yellow-cabs/ | grep -i 'googleads' ` gives nothing. What do you expect?

Comment: There is no `script` with `src="http://partner.googleadservices.com/gpt/pubads_impl_58.js"` in the response of the request that requests makes. It is loaded asynchronously.

Comment: @alecxe I see that the "async" attribute is indeed assigned to this nodes, is there a **reasonable** solution?

Comment: @GalB1t are you okay with automating a real browser?

Comment: I'm fine with that but its beyond the scope of this tiny project, thanks anyway @alecxe!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no script with `src="http://partner.googleadservices.com/gpt/pubads_impl_58.js"` in the response of the request that requests makes. It is loaded asynchronously.

As a workaround, you can automate a real browser with the help of [`selenium` package](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).

Example (using `PhantomJS` headless browser):

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> 
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>>> url = "http://www.euronews.com/2015/03/20/uber-taxis-overtake-new-york-yellow-cabs/"
>>> driver.get(url)
>>> for script in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//script[contains(@src, 'google')]"):
...     print(script.get_attribute('src'))
... 
https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.t-LxkuL3EUg.O/m=gapi_iframes_style_bubble/exm=auth,plusone,ytsubscribe/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IQ/rs=AGLTcCNAFql0FUItRCrv44X1do5tNb0b8Q/t=zcms/cb=gapi.loaded_3
https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.t-LxkuL3EUg.O/m=auth/exm=plusone,ytsubscribe/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IQ/rs=AGLTcCNAFql0FUItRCrv44X1do5tNb0b8Q/t=zcms/cb=gapi.loaded_2
https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.t-LxkuL3EUg.O/m=ytsubscribe/exm=plusone/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IQ/rs=AGLTcCNAFql0FUItRCrv44X1do5tNb0b8Q/t=zcms/cb=gapi.loaded_1
https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.t-LxkuL3EUg.O/m=plusone/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IQ/rs=AGLTcCNAFql0FUItRCrv44X1do5tNb0b8Q/t=zcms/cb=gapi.loaded_0
http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js
http://www.euronews.com/js/google.js
https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js
http://partner.googleadservices.com/gpt/pubads_impl_58.js
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20150331/r20150224/show_ads_impl.js
http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/check_359604.js
http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-3977141546397241&output=js&adk=2828788313&image_size=607x90&lmt=1428369754&num_ads=4&skip=0&ad_type=text&ea=0&oe=utf8&flash=0&hl=en&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.euronews.com%2F2015%2F03%2F20%2Fuber-taxis-overtake-new-york-yellow-cabs%2F&dt=1428355354776&shv=r20150331&cbv=r20150224&saldr=sb&correlator=6304440702977&frm=20&ga_vid=21319259.1428355355&ga_sid=1428355355&ga_hid=935959392&ga_fc=0&u_tz=-240&u_his=1&u_java=0&u_h=900&u_w=1440&u_ah=873&u_aw=1440&u_cd=32&u_nplug=0&u_nmime=0&dff=arial&dfs=12&biw=400&bih=300&eid=317150304&oid=3&rx=0&eae=2&fc=24&brdim=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1440%2C23%2C0%2C0%2C400%2C300&vis=0&rsz=0%7C0%7C%7C&abl=CS&ppjl=u&fu=1024&bc=1&ifi=1&dtd=155
>>>
```